# Share location between iOS and Android..?

Tags: applications, geolocation, ios

My wife and I find it really useful to share our locations with each other. Until now we both had iPhone's and were using the "Find my friends" app, but my wife is now using Android (Samsung S8).

I've looked at the "Trusted Contacts" app, but that only seems to share the location temporarily. We want to share locations permanently, without manually authorising all the time, and without annoying notifications.

Is there any way,  that works on both platforms to permanently share your location with someone else ?

Comment: [Family locator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.life360.android.safetymapd) on Play store claims to work with both. Not tested by me. See if that works

Comment: We don't want to send locations to each other, we want the same system as Apple's Find My Friends, but between iOS and Android. So, an app we can both set to permanently share our location, which we can fire up any time to see where the other person is.

Comment: In which case app in second comment seems to be a candidate. BTW asking for apps is off topic here so edited your wording. If you are not OK with it, you can roll back the edit and ask on softwarerec SE

Comment: Great, thanks @beeshyams... My apologies for being off-topic, I've not used this Android Enthusiasts site before.

Comment: Welcome. Test that app if that fits

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google maps has live location sharing, built in.

It works for both, iPhone and Android devices [according to Google support](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/7326816?co=GENIE.Platform%3DiOS&hl=en)

You can set it up in just a few steps:

Open Google maps, in the menu, select *location sharing.* There, it will ask how long you want to share your location for.  Select *until you turn this off* and choose an email account to share it with. (Both have to have a Google account to use this feature)

The same is done on an iPhone after downloading [Google maps](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/google-maps-gps-navigation/id585027354?mt=8).

Now, every time you open Google maps, it will show you exactly where the other person is located.

[image]